# Java REST api GET not returning json

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, get

I've been struggling with finding the cause of a 500 Error.. any tips would be appreciated.

Basically through a GET request I'm trying to return a list to my view in json. It's working with below classes:

Test class to check if sending json is data is working **TestObjectRestWs**:

```
@Path("testobject")
@Stateless
public class TestObjectRestWs {

    public TestObjectRestWs() {
        // empty constructor
    }    

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<TestObject> getAll(){

        List<TestObject> allTestObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        allTestObjects.add(new TestObject(1, "testContent1"));
        allTestObjects.add(new TestObject(2, "testContent2"));

        return allTestObjects;
    }

}
```

which works with the simple class **TestObject.java**:

```
public class TestObject {

    private int id;
    private String content;

    public TestObject(){

    }

    public TestObject(int id, String content){
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    // getters & setters..

}
```

So basically this confirms everything *should* work, however when I try to use it with my intended classes below it returns 500 instead of 200:

**TweetRestWs**

```
@Path("tweet")
@Stateless
public class TweetRestWs {

    @Inject
    private TweetService tweetService;


    public TweetRestWs() {
    }    

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Tweet> getAll(){

        List<Tweet> allTweets = tweetService.getAllTweets();
        // list contains Tweets
        return allTweets;        
    }
}
```

Which uses the object **Tweet**:

```
@Entity

// namedquery's... 
public class Tweet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TWEET_ID")
    protected int tweetId;

    protected String content;

    @OneToMany
    protected List<User> mentions;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "TAGS")
    protected List<String> tags;

    @ManyToOne
    protected User user;

    protected int favourites;

    public Tweet() {
        // no-args constructor for JPA
    }

    public Tweet(String content, User user){
        this.content = content;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // getters & setters ....
}
```

So I'm sure it has something to do with the class Tweet.java (some properties cannot be converted to json?), it's just complicated to debug and I don't know where to start.. Any tips will be welcome! Thanks

edit: headers on request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:39538/Tweeter/rest/tweet
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:39538
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Language:
Content-Length:1142
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 10 Dec 2017 18:00:17 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
Pragma:No-cache
Server:Payara Server  4.1.2.172 #badassfish
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (Payara Server  4.1.2.172 #badassfish                             Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=193c22a1b146918cd6531441d9ec
Host:localhost:39538
Referer:http://localhost:39538/Tweeter/views/user/angular.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm using this simple function to test (which *does* return a json array if I change the uri to /testobject):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.get("http://localhost:39538/Tweeter/rest/tweet", function(data){
                alert("Data: " + data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit2:

I set my server log level to FINEST and this is the log when I make the request:

```
Fine:   Security checking request GET /Tweeter/rest/tweet
Fine:   We have cached auth type FORM for principal 3@email.com
Fine:    Calling hasUserDataPermission()
Fine:   [Web-Security][ hasUserDataPermission ] Principal: 3@email.com ContextPath: /Tweeter
Fine:   [Web-Security] Setting Policy Context ID: old = null ctxID = Tweeter/Tweeter
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/rest/tweet" "GET")
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
Fine:   [Web-Security]  requestURI: /rest/tweet loginPage: /views/loginRealm.xhtml
Fine:   [Web-Security] [ hasResourcePermission ] Principal: 3@email.com ContextPath: /Tweeter
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Tweeter/Tweeter
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/rest/tweet" "GET")
Fine:   TM: enlistComponentResources
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=null, tm=null
Fine:   found cached proxy [com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.JavaModuleNamingProxy@48880702] for [java:module/TweetRestWs]
Fine:   Entering BaseContainer::preInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface webservices.__EJB31_Generated__TweetRestWs__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.List webservices.__EJB31_Generated__TweetRestWs__Intf__.getAll(),ejb=null,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   JACC: Access Control Decision Result: true EJBMethodPermission (Name) = TweetRestWs (Action) = getAll,Local, (Caller) = null
Fine:   TM: status: NoTransaction
Fine:   TM: status: NoTransaction
Fine:   --Created new JavaEETransactionImpl, txId = 23
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=null
Fine:   TM: enlistComponentResources
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=null
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetRestWs; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
Fine:   JACC: Changing Policy Context ID: oldV = Tweeter/Tweeter newV = Tweeter/Tweeter_internal
Info:   getAll called in TweetRestWs
Fine:   Entering BaseContainer::preInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface service.__EJB31_Generated__TweetService__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.List service.__EJB31_Generated__TweetService__Intf__.getAllTweets(),ejb=null,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   JACC: Access Control Decision Result: true EJBMethodPermission (Name) = TweetService (Action) = getAllTweets,Local, (Caller) = null
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetRestWs; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: enlistComponentResources
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetService; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   Entering BaseContainer::preInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface dao.__EJB31_Generated__TweetDAO__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.ArrayList dao.__EJB31_Generated__TweetDAO__Intf__.findAll(),ejb=null,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   JACC: Access Control Decision Result: true EJBMethodPermission (Name) = TweetDAO (Action) = findAll,Local, (Caller) = null
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetService; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: enlistComponentResources
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetDAO; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45], tm=null
Fine:   --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
Fine:   In EntityManagerWrapper::_getDelegate(). Logical entity manager  = com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper@327823e3
Fine:   Physical entity manager = org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@4ec7e3f8
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper$1@4309ccd9], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper$1@4309ccd9], tm=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper$1@4309ccd9], tm=null
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper$1@4309ccd9], tm=null
Fine:   --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=23 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@9661a45, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper$1@4309ccd9, org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener@7d2143a1], tm=null
Fine:   returning the connector registry
Fine:   RAR5036:Resource reference is not defined for JNDI name [jdbc/tweeterDatasource__nontx]
Fine:   returning the connector registry
Fine:   In equals
Fine:   Found/returing Connector descriptor in connector registry.
Fine:   ConnectionMgr: poolName tweeterMySQLPool  txLevel : 1
Fine:   Returning noTxResourceManager
Fine:   Resource Pool: elapsed time (ms) to get connection for [ResourceSpec :- 
connectionPoolName : tweeterMySQLPool
isXA_ : false
resoureId : jdbc/tweeterDatasource__nontx
resoureIdType : 1
pmResource : false
nonTxResource : true
lazyEnlistable : false
lazyAssociatable : false] : 0
Fine:   In getConnection
Fine:   Starting Init SQL
Fine:   Finished executing Init SQL
Fine:   Returning noTxResourceManager
Fine:   NoTxResourceManagerImpl :: enlistResource called
Fine:   Returning noTxResourceManager
Fine:   NoTxResourceManagerImpl :: delistResource called
Fine:   Pool: resourceClosed: 1
Fine:   In cleanup
Fine:    Wait monitor is null
Fine:   Pool: resourceFreed: 1
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetDAO; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetService; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetDAO; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   Leaving BaseContainer::postInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface dao.__EJB31_Generated__TweetDAO__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.ArrayList dao.__EJB31_Generated__TweetDAO__Intf__.findAll(),ejb=dao.TweetDAO@32ff27d7,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetService; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetRestWs; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetService; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   Leaving BaseContainer::postInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface service.__EJB31_Generated__TweetService__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.List service.__EJB31_Generated__TweetService__Intf__.getAllTweets(),ejb=service.TweetService@3e7561cd,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   JACC: Changing Policy Context ID: oldV = Tweeter/Tweeter_internal newV = Tweeter/Tweeter
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   --In JavaEETransactionImpl.commit, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
Fine:   TM: status: Active
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=null, tm=null
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetRestWs; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl ResourceHandler: TweetRestWs; id: [B@2a97e8e7
Fine:   Leaving BaseContainer::postInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=Tweeter_/Tweeter,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterface=interface webservices.__EJB31_Generated__TweetRestWs__Intf__,method=public abstract java.util.List webservices.__EJB31_Generated__TweetRestWs__Intf__.getAll(),ejb=webservices.TweetRestWs@51c1a24b,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler: null
Fine:   TM: componentDestroyedorg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer@7200b83f
Fine:   TM: resourceTable before: 0
Fine:   TM: resourceTable after: 0
Fine:   
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler: null
Fine:   TM: getTransaction: tx=null, tm=null
Fine:   TM: componentDestroyedorg.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter@102b040
Fine:   TM: resourceTable before: 0
Fine:   TM: resourceTable after: 0
Fine:   recycle()
```

But I do not see anything that points to an exception?

Comment: Your error 500 status code is far too generic for us to give you an answer. Please share the server log with us so that we can some up with some possible cause. Also we need to know the rest client you are using to invoke the service, any HTTP headers you set and so forth.

Comment: We definitely need more information to help you. Can you provide exception stack trace?

Comment: There's too little information here, but there's definitely something wrong with the getAllTweets() method. Also, have you tried changing all the fields to public inside Tweet? Just to remove that out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks @LukeBajada I will try that, also for the rest of the guys, there is NO exception thrown server-side, that's what makes it so difficult.. the method is called, the getAllTweets() returns a list with size > 0 so I think it has to be something with a field that doesn't get converted to json-format properly..

Comment: The Tweet and User classes are JPA managed, so it will be trying to serialise proxy classes, not the classes you have defined here, which is likely to fail. You'll either need to detach all of the objects or map the data into other classes to serialise. You probably also need to do something with your server logging config if you aren't seeing exceptions for this.

Comment: For now wrap your `List<Tweet> allTweets = tweetService.getAllTweets();` code with a try/catch and catch Throwable.  See if you get an exception that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found out what was the issue.. after setting log levels to finest I found out it was caused by an infinite loop (caused in the Tweet entity class)

it was fixed by adding

```
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="tweet") <--
@ManyToOne
protected User user;
```

Hope this helps someone in the future